# Displaying random gender(sex) Friend's Profile Picture using FQL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

```
if($user_gender == "male")
{
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid%2C+name+FROM+user+where+uid+IN+(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me())%20and%20sex='female'ORDER%20BY%20rand%20()%20LIMIT%201&access_token=".$access_token);
}
else
{
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+uid%2C+name+FROM+user+where+uid+IN+(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20me())%20and%20sex='male'ORDER%20BY%20rand%20()%20LIMIT%201&access_token=".$access_token);
}
```

In Graph Api Explorer its showing

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 100001242402868, 
      "name": "Don Omer"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to Extract UID from above data so that we can display his/her profile picture

```
$friend_pic = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://graph.facebook.com/".$fql_query_result['uid']."/picture?type=normal");
```

I am trying to create an app called "Who Will Marry Me".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate/continuation of [Display profile pic of female friend for male user (opposite sex)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12166598/display-profile-pic-of-female-friend-for-male-user-opposite-sex)

Comment: i have deleted my previous Question...

Comment: What's your problem? Why don't you just use the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one Query (and one API call). Try this:

```
$query = 'SELECT uid, name, sex, pic FROM user WHERE 
            uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
            AND NOT ( sex IN (SELECT sex FROM user WHERE uid = me())) 
          ORDER BY rand () LIMIT 1';
```

The quick and dirty way would be to do:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=" . urlencode($query) . 
         "&access_token=" . $access_token;
$spouse = json_decode( file_get_contents ($url));
printf('<p>You should marry %s. <img src="%s" /></p>', 
       $spouse->data[0]->name, 
       $spouse->data[0]->pic
       );
```

But you should really use the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php) as it is much more robust.